# The MutationObserver is not triggered when innerHTML is used by the documentElement node

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, innerhtml, mutation-observers

I've discovered the **MutationObserver** interface for intercepting and analyzing changes in the **DOM**.

It works very well and I've managed to intercept all DOM changes... with the exception of the **DOM** change via the `innerHTML` method when it's the `documentElement` node that uses it.

Here is my code:

```js
function test() {

  const config = {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
  };

  const callback = (mutationList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
      if (mutation.type === "childList") {

        for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
          if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() === "div") {
            console.log(node);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);
};

test();

document.documentElement.innerHTML += '<div>TEST</div>';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MutationObserver Example</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

The following JavaScript code:

`document.documentElement.innerHTML += '<div>TEST</div>';`

appears to completely rewrite the `HEAD` and `BODY` nodes.
This explains why the **MutationObserver** interface fails to intercept the addition of a `<div>` tag.

I'd like to know how to intercept **in this case**, the addition of a `<div>` tag to the **DOM**.

Comment: Did you try looking at `mutation.addedNodes`. It contains a `head`, `text`, and `body` nodes, no `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutation record is triggered:

```js
function test() {
  const config = {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
  };

  const callback = (mutationList) => {
    observer.disconnect();
    // StackSnippet's console's components have been removed by the innerHTML setter
    console.log(mutationList);
    document.body.append("Mutation triggered, check your browser's console");
  };
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);
};
document.querySelector("button").onclick = evt => {
  test();
  document.documentElement.innerHTML += '<div>TEST</div>';
};
```

```html
<button>Change &lt;html>'s innerHTML</button>
```

What happens is that for the HTML parser, the `<html>` element can only have 2 `Element` children:  a `<head>` and a `<body>`. No matter what input you give to the parser, it will produce at least the tree

```html
#Document
 <html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
 <html>
```

If you check the produced tree after your call, you'll see that indeed the `<html>` will contain an empty `<head>`, and a `<body>` which contains the `<div>TEST</div>` content:

```js
document.documentElement.innerHTML = `<div>TEST</div>`;

const pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.textContent = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
document.body.append(pre);
```

So in the `MutationRecord` you catch, there is no `<div>` in the list of `addedNodes` because the ones that have actually be added are the `<head>`, a text node, and the `<body>`, which will contain your `<div>`. If you want to catch these, you need to check the content of the `addedNodes`.

```js
// StackSnippet's console is disabled by the code below
// So we implement our own "logger".
const log = (content) => {
  const pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.textContent = content;
  document.body.append(pre);
};

function test() {
  const config = {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
  };
  const callback = (mutationList) => {
    observer.disconnect(); // trigger once
    for (const { addedNodes } of mutationList) {
      for (const node of addedNodes) {
        log(`Created node: ${node.nodeName}`);
        for (const div of node.querySelectorAll?.("div") || []) {
          log(`Added a new DIV: ${div.outerHTML}`);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);
};
document.querySelector("button").onclick = evt => {
  test();
  document.documentElement.innerHTML += '<div>TEST</div>';
};
```

```html
<button>Change &lt;html>'s innerHTML</button>
```

Now it should be noted that *it is possible* to `append()` a `<div>` as a direct child of the `<html>`, so you may want to add a line that checks that the `addedNode` `.matches?.("div")`, but if this happens, something is certainly messed up somewhere.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It is working well. However, I do not understand this for loop : `for (const { addedNodes } of mutationList)`
This is useless isn't it?